# Sublime Text 2 Reading python input from a file

Tags: python, bash, text, sublimetext2, interpreter

Here is my current python ST2 build file (default one)

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "${file}"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

What i want to when i press ctrl+b in the editor is the equivalent of running `python -u file_name.py < input.txt` command from terminal.

I tried editing the above file to

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "${file} < input.txt"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

But i get an error

> python: can't open file '/home/mike528/t.py < input.txt': [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory

I mean it's pretty clear what i want to do and what the error is i just have no idea how to separate the file name and actually do that.

Comment: Could you try ["python", "-u", "${file}", "<", "input.txt"]

Comment: Gives "EOFError: EOF when reading a line", it's like it doesn't recognize the command. I also tried ["python", "-u", "${file}", "< input.txt"] same thing

Comment: How about `["cat input.txt | python", "-u","${file}"]`

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory -------
[cmd:  [u'python | cat ~/input.txt', u'-u', u'/home/mike528/s.py']] ----
[dir:  /home/mike528] ---
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games]          This is the error i get after the above command, funny enough both of the methods work just fine when i type them in terminal, i can just type python name.py < input.txt and it works just fine, must be a path error or something.